# POWERSHELL To get the directory excluding file

Tags: powershell

I used the below code to locate where my powershell executable file is located

```
$FullPathName=$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
function global:GET-SPLITFILENAME ($FullPathName) 
{
$PIECES=$FullPathName.split(“\”) 
$NUMBEROFPIECES=$PIECES.Count 
$FILENAME=$PIECES[$NumberOfPieces-1] 
$DIRECTORYPATH=$FullPathName.Trim($FILENAME) 
return $DIRECTORYPATH
}
```

I got it as directory E:\product\powershell\

Now inside the this directory I have the below text files

```
E:\product\powershell\Servers.txt
E:\product\powershell\SchedulerTasks.txt
```

Please suggest a easy way to locate these files and get data from it?
Can we eliminate the above function with a single line code?

```
$ServerList = get-content Servers.txt
$SchedulerJobs = get-content SchedulerTasks.txt
```

Also please help me find all the subfolders inside E:\product\powershell\

```
we have
 E:\product\powershell\ps1
 E:\product\powershell\ps1\code
 E:\product\powershell\ps1\db
 E:\product\powershell\web\code
 E:\product\powershell\web\code\a
 E:\product\powershell\web\code\a\b
 E:\product\powershell\web\code\a\b\c
 etc

I was using something like this 
 $table = get-childitem "powershell" -recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer}

The location is E:\product\powershell\ is not fixed it may vary based on location of   
powershell executable
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$ServerList=join-path (split-path $myinvocation.mycommand.path -parent) servers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your really worked hard to get results that are build into PowerShell:

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

IMO if you don't want to provide the full path within your script to files within scripts directory, you can use `Push/Pop-Location`:

```
Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Push-Location
$ServerList = Get-Content Servers.txt
$SchedulerJobs = Get-Content SchedulerTasks.txt

# ... do your stuff...

Pop-Location
```